# Grammatical explanation of statement "He will not be questioned."

Tags: meaning-in-context, tenses, modal-verbs, modality

Seems to me that it is equivalent to "He is not to be questioned." There's an element of declaration or assertion I can't pin down!

Context is Stephen Miller speaking about Trump's travel ban, asserting that his power to block immigrants is absolute. I wondered how the tense and grammar was able to suggest this.

Comment: Without context it’s impossible to say which of several meanings this intends.

Comment: Questioning him will not happen // I'm not going to allow you to question him // He refuses to be questioned.

Comment: So it asserts his power not to allow questioning? It's prohibitive? The "will not" is not primarily used as future?

Answer (score 1):

## Deontic *will*

Like all modal verbs, *will* has both an [epistemic sense and a deontic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_modality) sense. You’re more used to the epistemic one, but this is a deontic use of *will* not an epistemic one.  That means it is **not** about the future. Only epistemic *will* is about the future.

A deontic sense is telling you what **must** be, not what by and by is going to be. That means it is a command, just like in *You shall have no other gods before me.*  That's using *shall* with the force of *must*.  This is doing the same with *will*. This is exactly how the [RFC 2119](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2119.txt) standard uses this language. It means it is an absolute requirement, just like a commandment. It is a command.

It’s also dubiously cast in the passive voice with an unspoken agent. The unspoken agent is the person addressed, or all the world. Since we’re now into issuing commandments, let me rewrite that for you into a more recognizable, Old-Testament sort of style of commandment:

### “Thou shalt not question him.”

That’s all it means: *you must not question him*.  Writer H. Rider Haggard’s Queen Ayesha was hardly the first leader who came to be known as [*She-Who-Must-Be-Obeyed*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/She:_A_History_of_Adventure), nor has she proven to be the last. The "must be obeyed" thing is very common in leaders of a certain bent, although how this is expressed is usually less um, “Biblically” phrased than in your example.

#### More deontic *will* uses

A different but related use of deontic *will* can be found in the first part of an *if* statement:

- If you will please sit down, we can get going.

That’s not the epistemic future, which is banned in *if* clauses in English. It’s a deontic use of *will* which here means:

- If you are willing to sit down, we can get going.

You can also find it in:

- Do what you will.

where *will* here carries the sense of *want*, so it means the same thing as:

- Do whatever you want to do.

Comment: +1 ["You shall not pass"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mJZZNHekEQw)

Answer (score -1):

***He is not to be questioned*** sounds like a declaration made about someone being above said questioning, while ***He will not be questioned*** just sounds like a declaration that he refuses to be questioned.

Comment: Hi @Erin-Kate Sousa, I have to disagree a bit. How can you characterize **He will not be questioned** as _solely_ a refusal? It's essentially the same as the first example; it sounds like a directive meaning that questioning of a certain individual _will not be allowed_.

Comment: I don't think I characterized it as solely a refusal, I said it sounded like one, because he is not to be questioned is more definitive sounding than he will not be questioned- will not implying some choice in the matter.